# Formulate necessary, but not sufficient, conditions for a triangle to be a right triangle.

Tags: logic

This is a question from an intro class on logic. I am aware that "sufficient and necessary" refers to $ \iff $ The equivalency relation. As well as "sufficient but not necessary" refers to $ \Rightarrow $ The implication relation. However, I am confused about what "necessary but not sufficient" means in this question. Assuming that this is referring to the converse implication relation $ \Leftarrow $, I am still left unsure about how to approach this question. Would the Pythagorean theorem work as a necessary but not sufficient condition for example? Something like: $$ \sqrt[2]{a^2 + b^2} = c \Leftarrow Right\,\,Triangle $$  Though this would mean that there is a situation where the square of the sum of sides equals the square of the hypotenuse but the triangle is not a right triangle. I can't think of any situations like that. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: No, that is sufficient as well.

Comment: If all you want is an example, "a natural number $n$ is even" is a necessary but not sufficient reason to conclude that $n$ is divisible by $4$.

Comment: ‘Is a triangle’

Comment: No angle can be obtuse (i.e. greater than $~90^\circ~$).

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha and \beta<90°$ is necessary but not sufficient for $\gamma=90°$.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, anything true about (all) triangles that is not always true about right triangles is a necessary by not sufficient condition for a triangle to be a right triangle.